# Wordpress the_content(); showing content and attachements

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress 3.6 and advanced custom field plugin 4.2.1.

advanced custom field settings - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15109395/q/acf-media.png

my post - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15109395/q/page-content.png

my single page code

```
<section id="contentLeft" class="single">   
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); the_content(); }?>
</section>
```

Result - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15109395/q/page-front.png

but , i don't want that attachment image on content area. my local installation have no problem. not showing attachments. but my live website showing  attachment uploaded to that post.
how can i solve this issue? please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem solved with this solution. Thanks.
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/thumbnails-magically-appearing-on-all-pages

Answer (score 0):

if you want remove images from all posts and pages, simple copy the following code into your theme `functions.php`

```
<?php
function remove_images( $content ) {
   $postOutput = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','', $content);
   return $postOutput;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_images', 100 );
?>
```

it will remove the images wherever `the_content()` have images

else you need to include this function in specific page , put the following code

```
<?php remove_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_images' ); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. but thats not a perfect solution. that function remove inserted image. i don't want attachment images on the_content() function. but i want inserted iamge on the content area. can you have any suggestion.

Comment: What you mean by attached image? is featured image?

Comment: found reason. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/thumbnails-magically-appearing-on-all-pages . Thanks.